# Servicestack SerializationException: Could not deserialize 'application/json'

Tags: c#, android, json, servicestack, deserialization

Some requests from Android devices makes our servicestack.net service fail with this exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Could not deserialize 'application/json' request using CSharpRequestMappedObject'
Error: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdSyncReadRequest(IntPtr pHandler, Byte[] pBuffer, Int32 offset, Int32 cbBuffer, Int32& pBytesRead)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadEntityCoreSync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.CreateContentTypeRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, Type requestType, String contentType)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.CreateContentTypeRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, Type requestType, String contentType)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.GetRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)
```

I know it has somethink to do with the Post'ed json data could not be parsed to the CSharpRequestMappedObject.

Mapped like this:

```
[Route("/RequestPath/", Verbs = "POST"), UsedImplicitly]
public class CSharpRequestMappedObject
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public IList<SomeClass> Items{ get; set; }
    public bool State { get; set; }
    public string SpecialType { get; set; } //Not required
}
```

**My question is how do I figure out what that is wrong with the request?** 
It only happens sometimes - I see it in my server log, but I am not able to reproduce it.

I have tried this in global.asax:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{       
    ServiceExceptionHandler = (request, ex) =>
    {
        //Enrich exceptions with request body data.
        var propertyInfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetType().GetProperty("EntityBody", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var postBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])propertyInfo.GetValue(HttpContext.Current.Request, null));

        throw new Exception("Request body: " + postBody, ex);
    };
}
```

It adds request body data on other exceptions - but this exception is not catched there. (I have some other logging that catch the exception latter - elmah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended figuring out that the exception actually were caused by another exception throw moments after: HttpException: Request timed out.
I always occurs about 5/100 of a second latter.

Therefore, the cause is bad connection on the Android device, which makes sense with its rare occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend following

- Start using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to track request and response going back and forth
- Use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your json passing as input.
- Add constructor in request DTO that creates new object of Items like `public CSharpRequestMappedObject() { Items=  New List<SomeClass>(); }`

These are some general guidelines, please post your json input so that I can recommend some more precise hints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - we ended figuring out that the cause was that the requested timed out.

Answer (score 0):

While I realize this question is old the problem still exists and appears to be due to malformed or unterminated entity bodies being sent by `PATCH` requests from Android devices, rather than being an IIS or .NET problem.

The problem can be seen when a .NET application hangs for several (or many) seconds and eventually throws the following error as Morten describes above:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdSyncReadRequest(IntPtr pHandler, Byte[] pBuffer, Int32 offset, Int32 cbBuffer, Int32& pBytesRead, UInt32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadEntityCoreSync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Int64 timeout)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
```

The exception occurs when an Android device issues a PATCH request (containing an entity body) using a *protocol-relative URL*. **If the URL is changed to include a protocol the problem goes away**.

I've tested this with GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE and OPTIONS verbs and only found it to occur with PATCH.

I've also tested the same combination of verbs with Windows 7 desktop browsers (Chrome 41, IE11 and Firefox 36) and devices running iOS 8.2 and Chrome 40 on Android 4.4.2, both with protocol-qualified and protocol-relative URLs.

Of all these verb/platform/browser/protocol combinations I've only had the error thrown when issuing PATCH requests from an Android device using protocol-relative URLs. If an entity body is not included no error occurs.

Additionally I first suspected it might have something to do with cross-origin requests. However, after testing the combinations above I found no difference whether requests were cross-origin or same domain. Likewise, it made no difference whether the entity body was JSON or plain text. All tests were done using jQuery's .ajax() method in version 2.1.3.

I don't have an answer for how to better trap the error (or prevent it from occurring on the server, perhaps by performing some pre-processing), but I thought it would helpful to know what type of incoming request causes it.